# improving jsp looks?

Tags: jsp

i am using jsp with struts .
I want to improve the looks (user interfaces / web page appearance) .
How do i go a about.
I am using a style sheet now . But I am not a good HTML  degigner.
Can anyone provide me a nice style sheet .
I am doing a Course management system project and I am a student.
please help
does jsp support any inbuild support for this??
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP itself doesn't have a direct influence on the look of your webpage.

The design depends on the html output from your jsp page and the style sheets you are using.

If you are looking for a ready designed css template, there are several web pages

i.e. http://www.freecsstemplates.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be best off reading some basics on usable design, use of white space, use of fonts, use of colour, etc, in general in order to improve your design skills. Most stuff is common sense once you've learned it. Have you sat down with pencil and paper to get some user-journey storyboards for the website appearance going?